# PHP reload not working?

Tags: javascript, html

i have read a tutorial on the internet which said that this way i can make a site load contect with no reload but it does not seem to work

heres my code:

I would want it to display the query.php file results under the 'send' button when date selected from dropdown and clicked.

```
<form method="post" action="query.php"> 
<select id="textarea" name="textarea" style="height: 42px;margin-top: 2px;">
<option value="1980" selected>1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="inputuno" value="Submit" class="btn btn-theme">Check!</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function recp(id) {
$('#myStyle').load('query.php');
}
</script>


<div id='myStyle'>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no php reload function in your code.  Also, can you show what it's doing?

Comment: Looks like you want a different query depending on the option that is selected, probably. Do tell. I can only guess that you want to load a different page based on what is `:selected`, and not just `query.php`. If you want to use the same page you'll need to use `AJAX` to send data to get the results you desire. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Who is calling that `recp(id)` function? I'd say nobody. If nobody is calling it, it won't run. If it won't run, it won't conduct the page load.

You need to call that function from somewhere.

Also, so far this seems to be more of a JavaScript/jQuery issue than a PHP one.

---

If you'd like the form to be sent, you'll need to add an `onsubmit` handler. I'd suggest taking a look **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)** and **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript)**.

Comment: isnt the DIV calling it? please help im complete noob this is the only thing i need(js ); /

Comment: @JohannaFoster No. Why would it? The DIV is just a display element. It can have handlers, but those need to be set up by you. I'd guess you need to provide an `onsubmit` handler to the **form**, one that invokes that `recp(id)` function. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: To have the div call it, you need to actually call the function.  `<div id="myStyle">
  <script>recp(id);</script>
</div>`

Comment: @JohannaFoster Wait a minute! Did you plot your `<option>` elements within a `<textarea>`? Why? ...Ah, okay, the name misled me...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textarea').onchange(function() {.
  $('#myStyle').load('query.php',  {textarea: $("#myselect option:selected").val() });
});
```

if I correctly understood what you are looking for. It will automatically reload when option will be changed. If you want to reload when button is clicked just add id property on it, for example "relbutton" and change type to "button".

```
$('#relbutton').click(function() {.
  $('#myStyle').load('query.php',  {textarea: $("#myselect option:selected").val() });
});
```

Also you need to get rid of those  tags, they are completely unecessary here.